# Comment Flag Type Colours

Tags: script

*This userscript is part of [SOMU (SO-mod-userscripts)](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts)*

## [Comment Flag Type Colours](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/CommentFlagTypeColours.user.js)

- Works on user's comment flag history group page

  [image: screenshot]
- Works on user's mod comment history pages

  [image: screenshot]
- Works on mod comment flag queues

  [image: screenshot]

### License

[MIT](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/LICENCE)

### Download

**[View source](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/CommentFlagTypeColours.user.js) ([Install](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/CommentFlagTypeColours.user.js))**

Userscripts require [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net) to be installed on your browser.

If you are on Android, your browser options are [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) *(recommended)* or [Dolphin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser).

### Code

This userscript is part of [SOMU (SO-mod-userscripts)](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts)

[Bug reports](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/issues), Forks, and PRs welcome!